# Creating Exclude user list for permissions- Unix

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have this weird requirement where I want to restrict only few ids from executing "chmod"  commands

```
#which chmod
/usr/bin/chmod
#ls -lrt /usr/bin/chmod
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           10700 Jun 20 2012  /usr/bin/chmod
```

it has execute permissions to all. Can we create a exclusion group and somehow configure in such a way that permission are revoked only to those user.

The option I have is to create a group with all ids exept those ids I am to put in exception and change permission like

```
-r-xr-xr--    1 bin      New-grp          10700 Jun 20 2012  /usr/bin/chmod
```

This option I do not want to use because in my server have lots of users are there and it will take very long time to get approvals and all. Please Suggest any other way.

Comment: you could probably do this by creating another group and modifying its permissions while simultaneously removing its members from wheel

Comment: You may be able to use an ACL to do this.  This would override the permissions for specific users or groups.  The mechanisms aren't completely standard — the POSIX.1e group never got their proposed standard accepted (assuming it got as far as actually being proposed), though some systems do support something close.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler, will try this option.

Comment: Maybe SELinux could help you?

Comment: Be careful with doing this - by restricting access to `chmod` you don't necessarily prevent people from doing a `chmod` operation, which is doable via system call.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an ACL for it. Try this: http://howtoaix.blogspot.com/2013/05/acl-access-control-list.html

Comment: Just bear in mind that ACLs aren't supported on all filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to question what you're trying to accomplish.

You see, the `chmod` binary only really exists to hook a system call. Built into your operating system there's a system call - called cunningly `chmod()` which changes file permissions.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fchmod.2.html

```
   #include <sys/stat.h>

   int chmod(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
   int fchmod(int fd, mode_t mode);

   #include <fcntl.h>           /* Definition of AT_* constants */
   #include <sys/stat.h>

   int fchmodat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, mode_t mode, int flags);
```

etc.

It's a very bad idea to try and lock this functionality down by changing permisisons on the `chmod` command, because at best all you'll get is a false sense of security. `chmod` doesn't require any elevated privileges to run, so any user could copy their own version of it, and run that instead.

Or use a compiler to write their own.

Or use a perl builtin.

Or a variety of other mechanisms which basically mean this isn't going to accomplish very much apart from to be slightly irritating.

What are you *really* trying to accomplish? You're probably looking at some sort of mandatory access control, which'd mean you need to look at selinux.